# Creating a simple Chat application in Python (Sockets)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, synchronization, chat

I'm trying to create a simple chat application using sockets (python). Where a client can send a message to server and server simply broadcast the message to all other clients except the one who has sent it.

Client has two threads, which are running forever

> `send`: Send simply sends the cleints message to server.
>
> `receive`: Receive the message from the server.

Server also has two threads,  which are running forever

> `accept_cleint`: To accept the incoming connection from the client.
>
> `broadcast_usr`: Accepts the message from the client and just broadcast it to all other clients.

But I'm getting erroneous output (Please refer the below image). All threads suppose to be active all the times but Some times client can send message sometimes it can not. Say for example Tracey sends 'hi' 4 times but its not broadcasted, When John says 'bye' 2 times then 1 time its message gets braodcasted. It seems like there is some `thread synchronization` problem at sever, I'm not sure. Please tell me what's wrong.

[image]

Below is the code.

chat_client.py

```
import socket, threading

def send():
    while True:
        msg = raw_input('\nMe > ')
        cli_sock.send(msg)

def receive():
    while True:
        sen_name = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        data = cli_sock.recv(1024)

        print('\n' + str(sen_name) + ' > ' + str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    # socket
    cli_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # connect
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    cli_sock.connect((HOST, PORT))     
    print('Connected to remote host...')
    uname = raw_input('Enter your name to enter the chat > ')
    cli_sock.send(uname)

    thread_send = threading.Thread(target = send)
    thread_send.start()

    thread_receive = threading.Thread(target = receive)
    thread_receive.start()
```

chat_server.py

```
import socket, threading

def accept_client():
    while True:
        #accept    
        cli_sock, cli_add = ser_sock.accept()
        uname = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        CONNECTION_LIST.append((uname, cli_sock))
        print('%s is now connected' %uname)

def broadcast_usr():
    while True:
        for i in range(len(CONNECTION_LIST)):
            try:
                data = CONNECTION_LIST[i][1].recv(1024)
                if data:
                    b_usr(CONNECTION_LIST[i][1], CONNECTION_LIST[i][0], data)
            except Exception as x:
                print(x.message)
                break

def b_usr(cs_sock, sen_name, msg):
    for i in range(len(CONNECTION_LIST)):
        if (CONNECTION_LIST[i][1] != cs_sock):
            CONNECTION_LIST[i][1].send(sen_name)
            CONNECTION_LIST[i][1].send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    CONNECTION_LIST = []

    # socket
    ser_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    ser_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

    # listen    
    ser_sock.listen(1)
    print('Chat server started on port : ' + str(PORT))

    thread_ac = threading.Thread(target = accept_client)
    thread_ac.start()

    thread_bs = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_usr)
    thread_bs.start()
```

Comment: I think the issue is in your client thread loops, although your server needs to be able to handle client disconnect as well.

Comment: Just FYI, **Twisted** is a Python library for making threaded servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I lied in my comment earlier, sorry. The issue is actually in the `broadcast_usr()` function on the server. It is blocking in the `recv()` method and preventing all but the currently selected user from talking at a single time as it progresses through the `for` loop. To fix this, I changed the server.py program to spawn a new broadcast_usr thread for each client connection that it accepts. I hope this helps.

```
import socket, threading

def accept_client():
    while True:
        #accept    
        cli_sock, cli_add = ser_sock.accept()
        uname = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        CONNECTION_LIST.append((uname, cli_sock))
        print('%s is now connected' %uname)
        thread_client = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_usr, args=[uname, cli_sock])
        thread_client.start()

def broadcast_usr(uname, cli_sock):
    while True:
        try:
            data = cli_sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print "{0} spoke".format(uname)
                b_usr(cli_sock, uname, data)
        except Exception as x:
            print(x.message)
            break

def b_usr(cs_sock, sen_name, msg):
    for client in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if client[1] != cs_sock:
            client[1].send(sen_name)
            client[1].send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    CONNECTION_LIST = []

    # socket
    ser_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    ser_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

    # listen    
    ser_sock.listen(1)
    print('Chat server started on port : ' + str(PORT))

    thread_ac = threading.Thread(target = accept_client)
    thread_ac.start()

    #thread_bs = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_usr)
    #thread_bs.start()
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, But there is a minor bug. A sender has to send 2 messages in order to broadcast. Seems like `sen_name = cli_sock.recv(1024)` and `data = cli_sock.recv(1024)` at client side both are receiving sender name and message. Please refer the below screen shot
http://postimg.org/image/3mnwmuyvj/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get around the bug you said @Atinesh. The client will be asked a username once and this 'uname' will be included in the data to be sent. See what I did to the '***send***' function.

For easier visualization, I added a '\t' to all received messages.

```
import socket, threading

def send(uname):
    while True:
        msg = raw_input('\nMe > ')
        data = uname + '>' + msg
        cli_sock.send(data)

def receive():
    while True:
        data = cli_sock.recv(1024)
        print('\t'+ str(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    # socket
    cli_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # connect
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023

    uname = raw_input('Enter your name to enter the chat > ')

    cli_sock.connect((HOST, PORT))     
    print('Connected to remote host...')


    thread_send = threading.Thread(target = send,args=[uname])
    thread_send.start()

    thread_receive = threading.Thread(target = receive)
    thread_receive.start()
```

You also have to modify your server code accordingly.

server.py

```
import socket, threading

def accept_client():
    while True:
        #accept    
        cli_sock, cli_add = ser_sock.accept()
        CONNECTION_LIST.append(cli_sock)
        thread_client = threading.Thread(target = broadcast_usr, args=[cli_sock])
        thread_client.start()

def broadcast_usr(cli_sock):
    while True:
        try:
            data = cli_sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
               b_usr(cli_sock, data)
         except Exception as x:
            print(x.message)
            break

def b_usr(cs_sock, msg):
    for client in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if client != cs_sock:
            client.send(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    CONNECTION_LIST = []

    # socket
    ser_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # bind
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 5023
    ser_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

    # listen    
    ser_sock.listen(1)
    print('Chat server started on port : ' + str(PORT))

    thread_ac = threading.Thread(target = accept_client)
    thread_ac.start()
```

The things that changed in the server side are: the user who connected and the user who spoke is not seen anymore. I don't know if it would mean that much if your purpose is to connect clients. Maybe if you want to strictly monitor clients via the server, there could be another way.

Comment: There is an indentation error on line 17 in the server code. It just needs to be moved 1 char to the left.