# Python, I want to make Multiple Connection Chatting Program

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I coded chatting program with socket module.
(Python)

and I saw perfect send and get data.

But I found a problem.

This is my Server.py

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9999
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

print(addr)


def sendmsg():
    while True:
        data = input()
        data = data.encode("utf-8")
        conn.send(data)
    conn.close()


def getmsg():
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        if data is None:
            break
        else:
            data = data.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
            print(data)
    conn.close()


threading._start_new_thread(sendmsg, ())
threading._start_new_thread(getmsg, ())

while True:
    pass
```

Just on Client can connect with server.

I want to make multiple connection.

So I changed value of s.listen(1) to s.listen(2)
but It doesn't work.

Help me TT

This is client.py

```
import socket
import threading

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9999
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))


def sendMsg():
    while True:
        data = input()
        s.sendall(str.encode(data))
    s.close()


def getMsg():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        print(data)
    s.close()


threading._start_new_thread(sendMsg, ())
threading._start_new_thread(getMsg, ())

while True:
    pass
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you count how many client are in? Are you opening new command prompt and starting new process?

Comment: Yes. I start new process

Comment: That depends on is it windows or Linux? You should accept all new connections in While true loop.
You need to use IO Select or firgure out yourself how to proceed with multithreading

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/ He gave a good example how to write it on single machine Works on Linux

Comment: Thank you for your tip. and this is window.

Comment: If you want working solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060346/creating-a-simple-chat-application-in-python-sockets

Comment: I coded accept method. Your hint helped me  -You should accept all new connections in While true loop- .

Comment: Now I am making broadcasting

Comment: I think it will be not very hard. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://github.com/KairatKempirbaev/Real-time-local-network-chat
It is sending the same information twice but still you can find direction to improve your solution