# How do you execute a function while Python 3 is taking input from the user?

Tags: python

How do you execute a function, while the program is still taking input from the user, because all the code after

```py
user_input = input()
```

is not run until the user inputs something.

So how do I run a function while the user is typing an input?

Thank you!

Edit: People were asking why I need to do this, so I am making an online TextRPG game, where people can chat as well, but what I want is while you are typing, chat should update. Also I have not tried any code yet, because I don't get how to do it.

Comment: By running it on another thread. Why do you need to run a function while waiting for input?

Comment: share your code so we can see what you have tried. What are your desired output?

Comment: @JoeFerndz I have edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: It is not a simple answer. Why don't you research a bit and also look at some of the example posts in stackoverflow to get an idea of what you are trying to do. For ex: see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060346/creating-a-simple-chat-application-in-python-sockets

Comment: Have you researched what is required to create an online game written in python?  It is much more complex than you probably imagine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python async: Waiting for stdin input while doing other stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454190/python-async-waiting-for-stdin-input-while-doing-other-stuff)

Comment: Use `celery` https://docs.celeryproject.org. See also https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html and https://riptutorial.com/celery/example/23628/celery-plus-redis

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the concept of multi threading.

Answer (score -2):

```py
test_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: The question was: "*how do I run a function while the user is typing an input?*"